# Select the lower of two values in a table unless some criteria is met, then select the higher value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have analytical data that has results for two dilution factors. I would like to use the lower dilution factor unless the lab qualifier for that result is E. In those cases, I need to use the higher dilution value. The query below selects the correct records, but that's as far as I can get. I appreciate any help.

```
SELECT  
    s.task_code,  
    s.sys_loc_code,
    a.analyte_type, 
    a.chemical_name, 
    t.dilution_factor, 
    r.result_text, 
    r.lab_qualifiers
FROM 
    dt_sample s 
JOIN 
    dt_test t ON s.sample_id = t.sample_id AND s.facility_id = t.facility_id
JOIN 
    dt_result r ON t.test_id = r.test_id AND t.facility_id = r.facility_id  
JOIN 
    rt_analyte a ON r.cas_rn = a.cas_rn
WHERE 
    s.task_code= 'RFS01-10.1810009'
    AND s.sample_type_code IN ('F','D') 
    AND a.analyte_type IN ('Semivolatile','Volatile') 
    AND s.sys_loc_code IN ('15699', '45608', '90399', '91203', 'MOUND R1-0', '99305', 'MSETINF', '23296')
ORDER BY 
    s.sys_loc_code, a.chemical_name, t.dilution_factor;
```

Here is an example of the results. For the first two records, I would like to use dilution factor = 1, but in the second set of records, I would need to use dilution factor = 10

```
task_code   sys_loc_code    analyte_type    chemical_name   dilution_factor result_text lab_qualifiers
RFS01-10.1810009    15699   Volatile    1,1,1,2-Tetrachloroethane   1   0.333   U
RFS01-10.1810009    15699   Volatile    1,1,1,2-Tetrachloroethane   10  3.33    U
RFS01-10.1810009    15699   Volatile    cis-1,2-Dichloroethene  1   324 E
RFS01-10.1810009    15699   Volatile    cis-1,2-Dichloroethene  10  282
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rank those records with dilution_fact=E as a lower rank value(2) and the rest as(1), and after that sort by the dilution_factor as below

```
with data
  as ( 
SELECT  
    s.task_code,  
    s.sys_loc_code,
    a.analyte_type, 
    a.chemical_name, 
    t.dilution_factor, 
    r.result_text, 
    r.lab_qualifiers
FROM 
    dt_sample s ON f.facility_id = s.facility_id
JOIN 
    dt_test t ON s.sample_id = t.sample_id AND s.facility_id = t.facility_id
JOIN 
    dt_result r ON t.test_id = r.test_id AND t.facility_id = r.facility_id  
JOIN 
    rt_analyte a ON r.cas_rn = a.cas_rn
WHERE 
    s.task_code= 'RFS01-10.1810009'
    AND s.sample_type_code IN ('F','D') 
    AND a.analyte_type IN ('Semivolatile','Volatile') 
    AND s.sys_loc_code IN ('15699', '45608', '90399', '91203', 'MOUND R1-0', '99305', 'MSETINF', '23296')
  )
,ranked_results
  as (
select *
       ,row_number() over(partition by task_code
                                       ,sys_loc_code
                                       ,analyte_type
                                       ,chemical_name
                            order by case when lab_qualifiers<>'E' then 1 else 2
                                     end,dilution_factor) as rnk
  from data
)
select * 
  from ranked_results
  where rnk=1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, When I run the query above, I only get dilution factors of 1 so I don't get the alternate result for the results with a qualifer of E. Also, could you please explain the use of with data as( I appreciate your time.

Comment: with data(<your query>) would create an in-flight view which can be queried in the select statement. Eg: with data as (<your_query>) select * from data would give you the output as you have described. I am not able to fully understand your requirement. in the example, could you show what is the expected result

Comment: It should have been lab_qualifier that i meant to order by. I have edited the query

Comment: The query works perfectly. Thanks so much. I have never used rank before, but I'm sure going to use it now!

Comment: Going to take a bit of practice to understand everyting you did. Can you sugest any resources to learn/understand advanced sql? Seems like I try for hours and always end up asking for help. I really appreciate that you all are willing to help others.

Comment: Can you tell me how to delete the records I select using your code?

Comment: to delete the records that match the criteria, simple choose DELETE from ranked_results WHERE rnk=1

Comment: Thanks, I tried that in our test database and it worked! Really, thank you again.

Comment: Happy to help. If my answer has helped you please mark the answer as correct/ and useful

Answer (score 0):

You should to use the `CASE WHEN ... THEN` operator in the `SELECT` phase. It's will looks like a

```
SELECT  
CASE 
WHEN r.lab_qualifiers = 'E' and t.dilution_factor_1 < t.dilution_factor_2 THEN t.dilution_factor_1 -- select lower dilution_factor value
WHEN r.lab_qualifiers = 'E' and t.dilution_factor_1 > t.dilution_factor_2 THEN t.dilution_factor_2 -- select lower dilution_factor value
WHEN r.lab_qualifiers <> 'E' and t.dilution_factor_1 < t.dilution_factor_2 THEN t.dilution_factor_2 -- select higher dilution_factor value
WHEN r.lab_qualifiers <> 'E' and t.dilution_factor_1 > t.dilution_factor_2 THEN t.dilution_factor_1 -- select higher dilution_factor value
END AS "dilution_factor"
FROM 
    dt_sample AS s 
    JOIN ...
    WHERE ...
    ORDER BY ...
```

So, you need to represent more clearly what do you mean by "higher" and "lower" values, then one row of the `SELECT` returns only one value. Do you want to select values of *dilution factor* from different rows?

Comment: Thanks for the repsponse, I'll try to apply it to my query and let you know what I get.

Comment: `SELECT
    t.dilution_factor,
    CASE
      WHEN dilution_factor = 1 AND lab_qualifiers <> 'E' THEN MIN(dilution_factor)
      WHEN diltion_factor = 1 AND lab_qualifers = 'E' THEN MAX(dilution_factor) 
     ELSE NULL
     END AS result 
    r.result_text, 
    r.lab_qualifiers
FROM dt_facility f
JOIN
WHERE
ORDER BY` Can't get the code to format correctly this time. Used the back tic and CTRL + K. Anyway my code doesn't work. I'm not sure what I should use for column2 in your code. The only MIN MAX is the dilution factor. Thanks.

Comment: It's cannot to type a full code representation style in a comments. I made some changes in my query then it must would  been more correct. And cannot understand which criterias you have using to determine  higher and lower values of dilution factor . Do you want to find a **minimal** and a **maximal** of *dilution factor  values* from the one column?

Answer (score 0):

This is a prioritization query.  If I understand correctly:

```
with t as (<your query here without the order by>)
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when lab_qualifiers = 'E' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by task_code, sys_loc_code, analyte_type, chemical_name) as numEs,
             row_number() over (partition by task_code, sys_loc_code,    analyte_type, chemical_name
                                order by dilution_factor) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by task_code, sys_loc_code,    analyte_type, chemical_name
                                order by dilution_factor desc) as seqnum_desc
      from t
     ) t
where (numEs = 0 and seqnum = 1) or
      (numEs > 0 and seqnum_desc = 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I run the query (with my query, no order by) I get the following error: SQL Server Database Error: Incorrect syntax near 'row_number'. I'll look up row_number() to see if I can figure it out, but I would appreciate your help.

Comment: @SWalden . . . There was a missing comma on the previous line.

Comment: OK, now I got it ot work. Thank you!!! Had to change result_text = E to lab_qualifiers = E, but after that I got the expected results. Now I just have to learn row number and partition by. I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: @SWalden . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?  It seems like the simplest approach to solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Only changing the t.dilution_factor in SELECT to

(CASE WHEN r.lab_qualifiers='E' THEN 10 ELSE 1)

```
SELECT  
    s.task_code,  
    s.sys_loc_code,
    a.analyte_type, 
    a.chemical_name, 
    (CASE WHEN r.lab_qualifiers='E' THEN 10 ELSE 1) dilution_factor, 
    r.result_text, 
    r.lab_qualifiers
FROM 
    dt_sample s 
JOIN 
    dt_test t ON s.sample_id = t.sample_id AND s.facility_id = t.facility_id
JOIN 
    dt_result r ON t.test_id = r.test_id AND t.facility_id = r.facility_id  
JOIN 
    rt_analyte a ON r.cas_rn = a.cas_rn
WHERE 
    s.task_code= 'RFS01-10.1810009'
    AND s.sample_type_code IN ('F','D') 
    AND a.analyte_type IN ('Semivolatile','Volatile') 
    AND s.sys_loc_code IN ('15699', '45608', '90399', '91203', 'MOUND R1-0', '99305', 'MSETINF', '23296')
ORDER BY 
    s.sys_loc_code, a.chemical_name, t.dilution_factor;
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The example I gave doesn't show all the dilution factors, but what I need "select the lowest dilution factor unless the lab qualifier is E, then select the higher dilution factor.